# R: How to select subsets of a column and repeat this over several columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with 100 rows and 13 columns. The dataframe contains observation of 11 levels (control, group1, group2, ...)

| treatment | variable1 | variable 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| control | 1 | 3 |
| control | 2 | 4 |
| control | 0.5 | 2 |
| group1 | 1.2 | 1.2 |
| group1 | 3 | 6 |

1. I have to create the effect size of my groups. To do so I need to subset my data into the individual treatments of variable 1. Next, I have to use the subsets in a formula:

```
cohen.d(var1$group1, var1$control, na.rm = TRUE, hedges = T) %>% .$estimate
```

2. This steps have to be repeated to compare 10 different treatments with my control group.
3. The steps have to be repeated for each column (variable)
4. I want to store the output of the cohen.d formula in tibble

How to do these steps without having to much code? I tried it like this...

```
hedge_calc <- function(y){
  
  df <- data_single_response %>% select(c(y,), treatment)
  
  x <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(factor.list)){
    x[i] <- df %>% filter(., remark == factor.list[i])
  }
  
  h <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(factor.list)){
    h[i] <- cohen.d(as.numeric(as.character(unlist(x[[i]]))), as.numeric(as.character(unlist(x[[1]]))) 
                    , na.rm = TRUE, hedges = T) %>% .$estimate
  }
  c <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(factor.list)){
    c[i] <- cohen.d(as.numeric(as.character(unlist(x[[i]]))), as.numeric(as.character(unlist(x[[1]]))) 
                    , na.rm = TRUE, hedges = T) %>% .$conf.int%>% .[1]
  }
  
  d <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(factor.list)){
    d[i] <- cohen.d(as.numeric(as.character(unlist(x[[i]]))), as.numeric(as.character(unlist(x[[1]]))) 
                    , na.rm = TRUE, hedges = T) %>% .$conf.int %>% .[2]
  }


  
  result <- data.frame(hedges_g = unlist(h), lower = unlist(c),
                       upper = unlist(d), treat_vs_control = factor.list[1:11])
  
  print(result)
}

hedge_calc(3)
```

... and received my results by looping from column 2:13.
BUt because this is super confusing to read and error prone, I need to use a better code.

Do you have any ideas??

Many thanks to everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Let `df` be as follows

```
> df
  treatment variable1 variable2
1   control       1.0       3.0
2   control       2.0       4.0
3   control       0.5       2.0
4    group1       1.2       1.2
5    group1       3.0       6.0
6    group2       4.0       6.0
7    group2       5.0       7.0
```

Then you first split the data.frame according to the different treatment levels and then execute two `lapply()` statements to iterate both over the variables as well as the groups.

```
cohen_list <- lapply(2:ncol(df), 
                      function(y) lapply(2:length(df_list), 
                                    function(x) cohen.d(df_list[[1]][, y],  
                                                        df_list[[x]][, y], 
                                                        na.rm = TRUE, hedges= TRUE)$estimate))
```

Then you bind the lists together, transpose it into a useful format and convert it to a dataframe.

```
final_df <- cohen_list %>% 
            do.call("rbind", .) %>% 
            t %>% 
            as.data.frame
```

Finally, you adjust the row and column names with

```
rownames(final_df) <- setdiff(unique(df$treatment), "control")
colnames(final_df) <- colnames(df[,2:ncol(df)])
```

with the **final output**

```
> final_df
        variable1  variable2
group1 -0.7042911 -0.2055516
group2  -3.252463  -2.788406
```